# Session variable gets lost after publishing (works on dev machine)

Tags: c#, session, authentication, session-variables

A quick project I've been asked to knock together doesn't need crazy security, so, I've implemented a simple login screen that checks the Username & PW against the db.

```
User u = new User();
if (u.AuthenticateUser(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text))
   Session.Add("UserSeshAuthenticated", true);                    

Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx");
```

All the other pages share a MasterPage and in the `Page_Load` event:

```
if ((Session["UserSeshAuthenticated"] == null) || ((bool)Session["UserSeshAuthenticated"] == false))
        {
            fw.Write("UserSeshAuthenticated has been lost or something");

            string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx?retpath=" + path);
        }
        else
        {
            lblLoggedInUsername.Text = Session["UserSeshAuthenticated"].ToString();
        }
```

This all works very well on my development machine, but when I've published it to my server, by the time my MasterPage loads, it has lost the session variables.

Can anyone help ?... I'm supposed to have it live this afternoon & I didn't think I'd run into this problem !!!

Any help appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: On the server, is this app running in the server root?  If it is running in a folder, is that folder configured as an application/package, in IIS?

Comment: The app is running as an application, but not in the server root...
It's running under an application inside another application, inside the DefaultWebSite.

IIS > Sites > Default Web Site > App1 > MyProblemApp

Comment: It isn't on a web farm or load-balanced system is it?

Comment: No, it's not on either of those.

Answer (score 0):

In your login code, you add "UserSeshAuthenticated" to the session, but not the User object.  If the function u.AuthenticateUser() adds a copy of itself into the Session, that could be your problem.  Try adding that in your result block instead.  Like this:

```
User u = new User();
if (u.AuthenticateUser(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text))
{
   Session.Add("UserSeshAuthenticated", true);
   Session.Add("oUser", u);

   Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Hi tgolisch,  Thanks for trying to help.  Don't worry about that user object, that's not really the problem. It's the fact that the session is completely lost.  I've removed the lines of code that were unnecessary.

Comment: Just to confirm: you are detecting that the session is lost, because after you login, you get bounced back to the login.aspx page. Correct?  ...oh, also, did you notice that your Response.Redirect will happen whether the login succeeded or not?  (I updated my code example to show a change you might want to try)

Comment: The u.AuthenticateUser function does nothing to the session.... I tried adding the entire user object to the session, it made no change....  I am detecting / debugging the loss of session variable by writing to a text file at key intervals and examining afterwards..... Also "did you notice that your Response.Redirect will happen whether the login succeeded or not?"  No, I didn't notice that, what is wrong with my IF statement ?

Comment: "what is wrong with my IF statement" - on your login page, after "if (u.AuthenticateUser(txt...", since you don't have any braces after it, only the Session.Add() statement is controlled by the IF. The redirect will happen either way (as it is currently written).

Comment: Ahh, yes - sorry  tgolisch - I thought you meant the if statement that examined the session variables.